# instrument variable for bins of endogenous variable

Tags: categorical-data, econometrics, stata, instrumental-variables

In my research, for example, **trunk** is the endogenous independent variable of interest and **headroom** is the instrument variable for **trunk**. Both **headroom** and **trunk** is continuous variable.

Let’s assume the basic iv-regression follows like this

```
sysuse auto,clear
ivreg2 price displacement (trunk=headroom), robust
```

**My question is**: I want further study the effect of **trunk** on **price** at different level of **trunk**. How should I instrument for the bin of **trunk**?
In OLS, I can create 3 bins of trunk according to the value of trunk is high/middle/low, in stata:

```
sysuse auto.dta, clear
sum trunk, detail
gen trunk_high=(trunk>=`r(p75)')
gen trunk_mid=(trunk>`r(p25)' & trunk<`r(p75)')
gen trunk_low=(trunk<=`r(p25)')
reg price trunk_high trunk_mid trunk_low displacement, robust
```

​​
How can I instrument for trunk_high trunk_mid trunk_low
Or I can just use predicted value in first-stage:
(but how can I calculate the standard error?)

```
sysuse auto.dta, clear
sum trunk, detail
gen trunk_high=(trunk>=`r(p75)')
gen trunk_mid=(trunk>`r(p25)' & trunk<`r(p75)')
gen trunk_low=(trunk<=`r(p25)')

reg trunk displacement
predict trunk_hat

sum trunk_hat, detail
gen trunk_hat_high=(trunk_hat>=`r(p75)')
gen trunk_hat_mid=(trunk_hat>`r(p25)' & trunk_hat<`r(p75)')
gen trunk_hat_low=(trunk_hat<=`r(p25)')

reg price trunk_hat_high trunk_hat_mid trunk_hat_low displacement, robust
```